# Extracting digits after '=' only with negative number

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I am trying to extract digits only after "=" string

```
strings <- c("1t clever=120","3c stupid=-150 bad","5k high iq=150 good")
```

and tried

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]+","",strings,perl = TRUE))
```

which gives

```
[1] 1120 3150 5150
```

the expected output

```
120 -150 150
```

How can I get this output ?

Comment: Your expected output has not only non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(strings, "(?<==)-?\\d+"))
#[1]  120 -150  150
```

Answer (score 3):

With base R:

```
regmatches(strings, gregexpr('(?<==)-?[0-9]+', strings, perl = TRUE))
```